# C Switch Statments

Tags: c

Quick question, I'm writing a Grade letter program using only switch statements. With if statements I can easily use <, or > to designate a certain range. If the user inputs a number such as 93 I would have to list all the cases from 99-90 which is too redundant. I already wrote the program and it works fine, but I want to get away from bad code. Is there a more reasonable way to write this without listing multiple cases? Hope this makes sense...

Comment: What's wrong with `if` statements?

Comment: divide the grade by ten, ex: 73/10 = 7  (integer arithmetic)

Comment: Are you using the default: case in the switch...case construct? Please give me an example of what exactly your code does...

Comment: jim's answer may work, but `switch` is really the wrong approach to your problem.

Comment: I had an assignment I did awhile back that involved using if statements but I was interested in seeing if there was a way to use switch instead. The problem was that by doing so, you limit yourself to writing every single possibility which is ridiculous. Just was looking to have a good discussion on this problem. Thanks for the input guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to use a switch statement to determine where a value falls in a set of ranges.

If you want to generalize a bit, and avoid multiple if/else statements with hard coded conditions, you could create a map. i.e. you are essentially mapping a set of integers to a set of grades.

Below is a simple example that uses a table lookup to map scores to grades. You could also create a closed mathematical formula that maps scores to grades, and just compute the grade directly from the score, instead of looking it up via a table.  e.g. f(x) = floor(2*(x-50)/20) would map scores from [0,100] into integer grades in the range [0, 5]

```
typedef struct
{
    int rangeLow;
    char grade;
} RangeToGradeMap;

RangeToGradeMap[] scoreToGradeMapping =
{
    { 90, 'A' }
    { 85, 'B' },
    { 70, 'C' },
    { 60, 'D' },
    { 0,  'F' },
};

char GradeLookup(int score)
{
    size_t N = sizeof(scoreToGradeMapping)/sizeof(RangeToGradeMap);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (score >= scoreToGradeMapping[i].rangeLow)
        {
            return scoreToGradeMapping[i].grade;
        }
    }

    // If we got here, there was an error - we didn't find the range

    return '?';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char grade = GradeLookup(87);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, clearly he/she *does* want to!  (And in fact, it would nice to be able to switch on ranges.)  What you mean is, "you can't"...

Comment: Coming back to this in two years time really makes a difference. Nice job, I now can come up with something very similar and implement my own solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, the point of `switch` is to enumerate cases. You can put several different cases to do the same thing (the code will execute until the next `break`), but you have to enumerate the possibilities (or use `default` to cover **all** the possibilities other than the enumerated as a single case).

If you need to cover ranges - use `if`.

Comment: This is exactly what I discovered. It just didn't make sense to list every possible case from 0-100. I just wish you could use <, > operators in switch statements to cover a full range.

Answer (score 3):

[Under `gcc` you can do this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges):

```
switch (value)
{
   case 1...3:
      //Do Something
      break;
   case 4...6:
      //Do Something
      break;
   default:
      //Do the Default
      break;
}
```

but the code is (obviously) not portable to other C compilers.